# Generalize Qx_TO_Qy macro?

Tags: c

I am using a bunch of macros of type:

```
#define Q31_TO_Q30 (31-30)
#define Q31_TO_Q20 (31-20)
#define Q25_TO_Q15 (25-15)
etc.
```

I would like to generalize this without having to manualy add each case. `Q`s go from 1 to 31, so there would be huge number of lines to cover all cases.

`#define Q_TO_Q(x,y) (x-y)` seems easy, but I would like to continue using the same `Qx_TO_Qy` syntax because of the "backwards compatibility".

Is some kind of macro magic possible that would achieve this?

Comment: What is the relation between `31 to 30` , `31 to 20` ..so on?

Comment: While I don't think it's possible to do what you want, you should know that it's almost certainly a better idea to just write `31 - 30` than to use a macro for it.

Comment: _Because of backwards compatibility..._  Can you just leave the legacy code (macros), so existing clients needing it, have it, but then define your new generalized macros for newer processes.  Both can co-exist.

Comment: Sadly, no. Macros can't define other macros.

Comment: @JL2210 Could you add that as answer?

Comment: Sure. I'll do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sadly, no. Macros cannot define other macros.